# Variable crashes code

Tags: swift, uitableview

Sorry for the bad title, and I feel really dumb for asking this question.

I'm deleting a cell from my table and the first block of code runs just perfect, but when shortening the line by creating a variable the code crashes. Why?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {

            emojisByCategories[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
 }
```

This small change will cause a "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)" error

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        var emojis = emojisByCategories[indexPath.section]
        emojis.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Build on Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235)

Comment: Is that the full, complete error?

Comment: Creating that variable is a bad idea. You WANT to delete the entry from the actual array, not a copy of it. Leave your code as it is in the first part.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes

Comment: @Shades I was going to use the variable later to check if section was empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of arrays. `Array` in Swift is a struct which is a value type. When you assign an array to another variable, you are actually creating a copy of the array.

When you do:

```
var emojis = emojisByCategories[indexPath.section]
emojis.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

you are modifying the copy in `emojis`. Nothing in `emojisByCategories` is actually being changed as a result of this code.

So now you tell the table view that a row has been deleted but your data source hasn't actually changed at all so you get the crash telling you about an invalid number of rows in a section.

The line:

```
emojisByCategories[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

doesn't have the same problem because you are not making a copy of any array and the values in `emojisByCategories` are being updated as expected.

You can make your second set of code work by adding a third line:

```
var emojis = emojisByCategories[indexPath.section]
emojis.remove(at: indexPath.row)
emojisByCategories[indexPath.section] = emojis
```

That 3rd line updates `emojisByCategories` with the updated `emojis` array so now your code won't crash.